# Play Store ignoring requiresSmallestWidthDp on API 21+

Tags: android, google-play

I want to avoid installations of my app via the Play Store on non-tablet devices (anything with less than 600dp width).

As described in https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringTabletApps I'm using `<supports-screens>` with `requiresSmallestWidthDp` on the manifest but it seems like the store is **ignoring this property** (e.g. as I still see a Nexus 5 in the compatible-devices section on the Play Console)

As https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html notes, no other parameters should be needed for my `minSdkVersion 21`:

> If you're developing your application for Android 3.2 and higher, you should use these attributes to declare your screen size support, instead of the attributes based on generalized screen sizes.

So using `android:smallScreens="false"` etc. **should be avoided** as described in the docs. But **the store ignores** the new / preferred parameter.

---

What to do now? I want to have the app only available to devices with `requiresSmallestWidthDp=600` so I'll support a Nexus 7 as well.

But when using the legacy-parameter `largeScreens="true"` I'd allow installations on anything > 480dp which means way less space on the screen (actually I wanted to go for 720dp but a 7" device seems very common).

Answer (score -1):

Put below lines in manifest at after  for small and normal devices

```
<compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />

        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
    </compatible-screens>
```

Comment: Sry, this does not met my requirements.
(A) As the docs for `<compatible-screens>` says, it should not be used (and `<supports-screens>` is preferred if needed).
(B) I want to only exclude *smaller* devices / not *bigger* ones
(C) I'd need to specify *every* possible configuration (and update it when new devices come across I might not even know about)

Comment: Basically, `<supports-screens>` is there and it's what I want but the store does not take it into account (entirely).
I can filter non-tablet devices using `android:smallScreens="false"` etc, but this limits the granularity to the pre-defined sizes (small, large, xlarge etc.) and *large* starts with *460dp* which is the main bummer here (I need 600dp)